# Identifying duplicates rows only with respect to some columns

Tags: r, duplicates

I would like to create a variable (e.g. reap) taking the value TRUE only if the elements of some columns are duplicates of those of another row BUT the values on other columns are different.
The sample data will probably clarify my question:

```
    V1   V2  V3
1.   a    b   c  
2.   a    b   d 
3.   e    f   g
4.   e    f   g
```

For example, if we want a variable taking value TRUE when rows have same V1 and V2 but different V3, then this variable should look like the following:

```
    V1   V2  V3  reap
1.   a    b   c  TRUE
2.   a    b   d  TRUE
3.   e    f   g  FALSE
4.   e    f   g  FALSE
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: your questions isn't clear

Comment: Hi @Tanuj Yadav, let me rephrase in this way, hopefully it will help: if I have a dataset with 3 columns, I am looking for the rows that have the same values in the first two columns and different in the third one. Is it clearer now?

Comment: ok, i got it. But do u want a program or something else?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I am looking for a code in R.

Comment: and whats the expected complexity?

Comment: I know how to find duplicates and also how to do it with respect to some columns only. What I cannot manage to do is selecting only those duplicates which have different elements on the third column.

Comment: Oh, you want specifically on third column?

Comment: Yes, the elements on the third column have to be different

Comment: Updated my answer. Have a look

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to identify all duplicates of each column, and create a logical vector using `rowSums` and setting the condition `!= ncol(df)`

```
rowSums(sapply(df, function(i) duplicated(i)|duplicated(i, fromLast = TRUE))) != ncol(df)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

To only consider the third column

```
m1 <- sapply(df, function(i) duplicated(i)|duplicated(i, fromLast = TRUE))
rowSums(m1) == 2 & !m1[,3]
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```